# For every closed $F$ and $x \in X \setminus F,$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\overline{U} \cap F = \emptyset.$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable and completely metrizable space. Denote $F$ a closed proper subset of $X.$ Denote $d$ a metric on $X$ and $\overline{F}$ the closure of the set $F,$ that is, $\overline{F}$ contains all limit points of $F.$

> Question: Show that for every $x \in X \setminus F,$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such
>    that $\overline{U} \cap F = \emptyset.$

My attempt:

Since $x \in X \setminus F,$ we have $\delta = dist(x,F) = \inf\{ d(x,y): y \in F \} >0.$

Choose $U = \{ y \in X: d(x,y) < \delta/2 \}$ be an open neighbourhood of $x.$

Clearly $U \cap F = \emptyset.$
I claim that $\overline{U} \cap F = \emptyset.$

Suppose not. Let $z \in \overline{U} \cap F.$ By definition of limit point in a metric space, there exists a sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $U$ that converges to $z.$
As $z \in F,$ we have $z \not\in U$. Therefore, $d(x,z) \geq \delta/2.$
Since $z_n \in U$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ we have $d(x,z_n) < \delta/2.$

However, for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ we have 
$$d(z,z_n) \geq d(x,z) - d(x,z_n) > \delta - \delta /2 = \delta /2,$$
contradicts that $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $z.$

Hence, $\overline{U} \cap F = \emptyset.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: If $F$ is closed as you say, then why isn't $\bar{F}$ just $F$?

Comment: Anyway, $x$ has a neighbourhood $B(x,\epsilon)$ that is disjoint from $F$. You can take $U = B(x,\epsilon/2)$, since its closure is contained in the closed ball with radius $\epsilon/2$, which is in turn contained in the open ball with radius $\epsilon$. What you do looks to be equivalent to this, but I don't understand why such a long proof is necessary.

Comment: @user49640: I just want to denote the notion of closure of a set, and it just so happens the only subset I have before introducing closure is $F.$ In my question, closure is applied on an open set.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is a metric space, it is regular.  By regularity, as $x$ not in   closed set $F$, there are open disjoint $U,V$ separating $x$ and $F$, i.e.
$x \in U$, $F \subset V$.  Thus $x \in U \subset X \setminus V \subset X \setminus F$.
As $X \setminus V$ is closed, $\overline{U} \subset X \setminus V \subset X \setminus F$.
Thus the $\overline{U}$ and $F$ are disjoint.